# Множественное или единственное число существительного должно быть во фразе?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, во фразе "яд, отравляющий людям души", правильно писать "души" или "душу"? Т. е. слово "душа" нужно употреблять во множественном или единственном числе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) ***Яд, отравляющий людям души***. (2)  ***Яд, отравляющий людям душу.***

Оба варианта возможны. **По семантике** более подходящим является ед. число (душу вообще), а **по формальным признакам** желательно согласование во мн. числе.

Сравнить: Яд, отравляющий души людей (здесь только мн. число).

Пример:

«*Губительным ядом, отравляющим **наши души**, является зависть*» (Генри Филдинг).

Answer (score 1):

Подразумевающаяся назидательность фразы, из которой изъяты эти слова, намекает на широкий взгляд на проблему, излагаемую на уровне понятий, а не величин. Количество, или множественность, — здесь не главное. Так что верно: душу. Сочетание с предыдущим словом также не должно настораживать, ибо здесь оно синонимично «человечеству».